# My simulation gives error most of the time

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simulation of upgrading items in an mmo game to find out how much does it cost to get a fully upgraded item. The code is done but most of the time it gives me an error message:

Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

I think it may be caused of too many attempts. Here is the code:

```
import random

#This is the starting grade of the item. We're trying to make it through 9
grade=0

#Those are counting how many items are used.
def yang(x):
    yang.say+=x
yang.say=0
def w(x):
    w.say+=x
w.say=0
def b(x):
    b.say+=x
b.say=0
def r(x):
    r.say+=x
r.say=0

#This is the upgrading simulation.
def upgrade(grade):
    #c stands for chance. As the grade goes up, the chance of success goes down.
    c = 0

    if grade == 0:
        c = 91
        yang(100)
    elif grade == 1:
        c = 83
        yang(200)
    elif grade == 2:
        c = 71
        yang(300)
    elif grade == 3:
        c = 58
        yang(400)
    elif grade == 4:
        c = 49
        yang(500)
    elif grade == 5:
        c = 38
        yang(600)
    elif grade == 6:
        c = 25
        w(1)
        yang(450)
    elif grade == 7:
        c = 18
        b(1)
        yang(900)
    elif grade == 8:
        c = 7
        r(1)
        yang(1500)
        
    a = random.randint(1,101)
    print(a)
        
    #if it is successful grade goes up by 1
    if a <= c and grade != 9:
        grade+=1

    #if it is not, grade goes down by 1
    if a > c and grade != 0:
        grade -=1
        
    print("New grade: ",grade)
    
    #We're trying until it gets 9
    if grade < 9:
        upgrade(grade)

upgrade(grade)
        
print(yang.say,"k")
print(w.say)
print(b.say)
print(r.say)
```

Comment: 'yang', 'b', 'r, 'b' are function, how do you call `.say` item ?

Comment: They are standing for the items. The yang(x) function adds x to yang.say which is the count of yang needed.

Comment: You should use a `while` loop to repeat your simulation step.  Recursion is limited to something like 1000 levels.

Comment: It looks like `upgrade` is calling itself too deeply.  As `grade` approaches `9`, `c` gets smaller, and so the chances of `grade` being increased get smaller.  You should rethink your logic.  It would be easy to turn this into an iteration rather than a recursion, which would eliminate the recursion depth problem, but the basic logic problem would remain.

Comment: @jasonharper thats something I have no experience with. Can you please show me an example about it?

Comment: @MehmetDeler You should master iteration before using recursion.  Iteration is preferable when applicable, and it's much harder to shoot yourself in the foot with iteration.

Comment: in `yang.say` what is `yang` ? I only see the function and a function has no attribut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jasonharper and @tom-karzes I started all over and solved the problem. The problem was -as they said- the function was calling itself over and over again until the program crashes by overload. Here is the finished work if anyone is interested in:

```
import random

def yang(x):
        yang.say+=x
yang.say=0
def w(x):
        w.say+=x
w.say=0
def b(x):
        b.say+=x
b.say=0
def r(x):
        r.say+=x
r.say=0

def upgrade(grade):
        n = random.randint(0,100)

        if grade == 0:
            c = 91
            yang(100)
        elif grade == 1:
            c = 83
            yang(200)
        elif grade == 2:
            c = 71
            yang(300)
        elif grade == 3:
            c = 58
            yang(400)
        elif grade == 4:
            c = 49
            yang(500)
        elif grade == 5:            
            c = 38
            yang(600)
        elif grade == 6:
            c = 25
            w(1)
            yang(450)
        elif grade == 7:
            c = 18
            b(1)
            yang(900)
        elif grade == 8:
            c = 7
            r(1)
            yang(1500)

        if n <= c:
            return int(grade+1)
        if n > c and grade !=0:
            return int(grade-1)
        if n > c and grade == 0:
            return 0

def simulation():
    grade = 0

    while grade<9:
        grade=upgrade(grade)

t = int(input(""))
for q in range(0,t):
    simulation()

print(yang.say/t)
print(w.say/t)
print(b.say/t)
print(r.say/t)
```